# Можно ли защитить столбец MySQL от перезаписи?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, база-данных

Таблица `data` в БД:

```
data_id   value  user_id
1          999    20
2            0    80
```

В php-обработчик посредством ajax подгружаются данные, которые обработчик записывает в БД:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  //some code
  $query = 'INSERT INTO `data` (`data_id`, `value`, `user_id`) VALUES ';

  //some code
  $query .= ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data_id = VALUES(data_id), value = VALUES(value), user_id = VALUES(user_id)';
  //где в качестве user_id будет подставляться значение из $_SESSION['user_id']
}
```

В чем есть проблема:
я не могу контролировать данные, поступающие на вход обработчика, а это означает, что пользователь `user_id=80` может, скажем так, "угнать" строку с данными у пользователя `user_id=20`, сформировав строку на вход обработчика таким образом, что вместо `data_id=2` будет указано `data_id=1`, которая будет перезаписана под его `user_id`.

В качестве грубого решения "в лоб" вижу возможность предварительного запроса `SELECT` всех заранее известных `data_id` с проверкой их владельца, но

1. это лишний запрос,
2. запрос будет представлять конструкцию `SELECT ... IN`, что плохо скажется на производительности.

Вторичные/внешние ключи не определены, пока не вижу, чем мне это может помочь. Одновременно обрабатываемых записей может быть 
несколько сотен, кроме того, планирую использовать индексы, поэтому не рассматриваю запрос `UPDATE`.

Прошу совета, как решить эту задачу, может быть есть способ защитить от перезаписи однажды указанный `user_id` или посоветуете любое другое решение?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66426/discussion-on-question-by-118-64-----mysql--).